# How can an image be the full width of an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is JPEG File for Certificate, and I implement it for the backend developers in HTML table format
[image]

I try to figure out bottom image part full width, but I couldn't implemet as above image!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LankaBangla Finance</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgrey">

  <table style="width:794px;height: 800px;margin:1.5% auto;background-color: #ffffff;border:1px solid #ededed; padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <img width="200px" src="https://i.imgur.com/7zzr0JS.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <div>
          <img width="220" src="https://i.imgur.com/7hx10YB.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 48px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 48px;color: #5d1c58">
          Certificate</h1>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: lighter; color:#f69c38;letter-spacing: 5px; line-height: 34px;margin: 5px;display:block; font-size: 34px">
          of completion</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong style="font-size: 22px;font-style:italic; color:#666666">This is to certifies that</strong>
        <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color:#008540">Mr Khairul Hasan</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#737373;">has successfully completed 14 mandatory modules through LBFL e-Learning Academy</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;color:#d94579; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 24px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 24px">
          MODULE COVERED</h2>
        <strong style="color:#5b5b5b; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;line-height: 1.2">Internal Control And Compliance</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <img width="130" src="https://i.imgur.com/o5kcDS3.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0">
        <!--            <hr/>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0"><small>July,2020</small></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <!--            <small style="white-space: nowrap">LankaBangla e-Learning Academy</small>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td><img width="100%" src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" alt=""></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to check, I am guessing that you need to format as a table with inline styling because the certificate may be emailed. Am I right that that is a constraint?

Comment: Yes! All styles should be inlined and written in inline.

Comment: Answers so far are using aspects of CSS which not all email clients may implement. Have you tried taking that image out of the table so it's not subject to the table's margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can fix this by changing the image to a `positioned element` and ensuring it is positioned relative to the table.

Set the `position` CSS attribute on the table to `relative`

```html
<table style="position: relative;">
<!-- table content goes here -->
</table>
```

Set the `position` css attribute to `absolute`, and set the `left` and `bottom` attributes to `0` on the image:

```html
<img 
  style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;" 
  width="100%" 
  src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" 
  alt=""
>
```

I updated your code snippet to show how this works.

Hope this helps!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LankaBangla Finance</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgrey">
  <table style="position: relative; width:794px;height: 800px;margin:1.5% auto;background-color: #ffffff;border:1px solid #ededed; padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <img width="200px" src="https://i.imgur.com/7zzr0JS.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <div>
          <img width="220" src="https://i.imgur.com/7hx10YB.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 48px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 48px;color: #5d1c58">
          Certificate</h1>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: lighter; color:#f69c38;letter-spacing: 5px; line-height: 34px;margin: 5px;display:block; font-size: 34px">
          of completion</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong style="font-size: 22px;font-style:italic; color:#666666">This is to certifies that</strong>
        <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color:#008540">Mr Khairul Hasan</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#737373;">has successfully completed 14 mandatory modules through LBFL e-Learning Academy</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;color:#d94579; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 24px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 24px">
          MODULE COVERED</h2>
        <strong style="color:#5b5b5b; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;line-height: 1.2">Internal Control And Compliance</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <img width="130" src="https://i.imgur.com/o5kcDS3.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0">
        <!--            <hr/>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0"><small>July,2020</small></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <!--            <small style="white-space: nowrap">LankaBangla e-Learning Academy</small>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <img style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;" width="100%" src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Edit: Added a version that should be email friendly. This swaps out the use of a positioned element for a div that wraps the table and img as siblings, and uses some hacky negative margin to make it look how you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LankaBangla Finance</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgrey">
  <div style="width:794px; margin:1.5% auto; background-color: #ffffff; border:1px solid #ededed;">
  <table style="width:794px;height: 800px;padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <img width="200px" src="https://i.imgur.com/7zzr0JS.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <div>
          <img width="220" src="https://i.imgur.com/7hx10YB.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 48px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 48px;color: #5d1c58">
          Certificate</h1>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: lighter; color:#f69c38;letter-spacing: 5px; line-height: 34px;margin: 5px;display:block; font-size: 34px">
          of completion</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong style="font-size: 22px;font-style:italic; color:#666666">This is to certifies that</strong>
        <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color:#008540">Mr Khairul Hasan</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#737373;">has successfully completed 14 mandatory modules through LBFL e-Learning Academy</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;color:#d94579; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 24px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 24px">
          MODULE COVERED</h2>
        <strong style="color:#5b5b5b; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;line-height: 1.2">Internal Control And Compliance</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <img width="130" src="https://i.imgur.com/o5kcDS3.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0">
        <!--            <hr/>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0"><small>July,2020</small></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <!--            <small style="white-space: nowrap">LankaBangla e-Learning Academy</small>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <img style="margin-top: -4rem; margin-bottom: -1rem" width="100%" src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" alt="">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works fine on my browser, but do all email clients implements position: absolute? I suspect they don't.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for the comment! I didn't see your earlier comments about email. Updated my answer to include a version that doesn't use positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `border-collapse: collapse` to the `<table>`

```
<table style="width:794px;height: 800px;margin:1.5% auto;background-color: #ffffff;border:1px solid #ededed; padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
```

2. Add `padding: 0; line-height: 0;` to the `<td>` with the image

```
<td colspan="3" style="padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
```

3. Remove the embedded table to remove additional spacing

```
<td colspan="3" style="padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
  <img width="100%" src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" alt="">
</td>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LankaBangla Finance</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgrey">

  <table style="width:794px;height: 800px;margin:1.5% auto;background-color: #ffffff;border:1px solid #ededed; padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <img width="200px" src="https://i.imgur.com/7zzr0JS.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <div>
          <img width="220" src="https://i.imgur.com/7hx10YB.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 48px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 48px;color: #5d1c58">
          Certificate</h1>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: lighter; color:#f69c38;letter-spacing: 5px; line-height: 34px;margin: 5px;display:block; font-size: 34px">
          of completion</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong style="font-size: 22px;font-style:italic; color:#666666">This is to certifies that</strong>
        <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color:#008540">Mr Khairul Hasan</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#737373;">has successfully completed 14 mandatory modules through LBFL e-Learning Academy</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;color:#d94579; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 24px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 24px">
          MODULE COVERED</h2>
        <strong style="color:#5b5b5b; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;line-height: 1.2">Internal Control And Compliance</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <img width="130" src="https://i.imgur.com/o5kcDS3.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0">
        <!--            <hr/>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0"><small>July,2020</small></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <!--            <small style="white-space: nowrap">LankaBangla e-Learning Academy</small>-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0; line-height: 0;">
        <img width="100%" src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This seems to have removed white space left and right which is maybe wanted?

Comment: If you check the design, the table has 40px padding; for collapse attribute padding is not working!

Comment: Padding would need to be declared on the applicable `<td>`s. I started to edit my answer to include this, but kept wanting to fix the rest of the table and decided to let it go.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to make some adjustments to the table structure and CSS styling. Specifically, you can use the 'colspan' attribute to make the bottom image cell span across all columns in the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LankaBangla Finance</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightgrey">

  <table style="width:794px;height: 800px;margin:1.5% auto;background-color: #ffffff;border:1px solid #ededed; padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <img width="200px" src="https://i.imgur.com/7zzr0JS.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <div>
          <img width="220" src="https://i.imgur.com/7hx10YB.png" alt="lanka-bangla">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 3px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 48px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 48px;color: #5d1c58">
          Certificate</h1>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: lighter; color:#f69c38;letter-spacing: 5px; line-height: 34px;margin: 5px;display:block; font-size: 34px">
          of completion</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong style="font-size: 22px;font-style:italic; color:#666666">This is to certifies that</strong>
        <h1 style="font-size: 40px; color:#008540">Mr Khairul Hasan</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;color:#737373;">has successfully completed 14 mandatory modules through LBFL e-Learning Academy</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;color:#d94579; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: bold;line-height: 24px;margin-bottom: 5px;display:block; font-size: 24px">
          MODULE COVERED</h2>
        <strong style="color:#5b5b5b; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;line-height: 1.2">Internal Control And Compliance</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0">
        <!-- <hr/> -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0" colspan="4"><small>July,2020</small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <img width="100%" src="https://i.imgur.com/TNICjPS.png" alt="">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>

> `Blockquote`
```

I have made the following changes to the code:

In the last row, I set the 'colspan' attribute of the bottom image cell ('') to 4, which means it spans across all columns in the table.

I removed the nested table and directly placed the image in the bottom image cell.

With these changes, the bottom image should now fill the full width of the table.

Comment: Could you check your code?

Comment: The image still has padding around it, unlike the desired result in the image.